# Android room migration for new table

Tags: android, android-room

I have an android app which is already use database with some tables in it. I also create a new table.

Do I need a migration for that? Or Room can handle it in automatic way?

Comment: You will need migration for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need a migration for that. You can migrate manually or from Room version `2.4.0-alpha01` you can use [automated migrations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

Comment: Yes, I see. When you change the existing database and update db version you need a migration. In my case I cleaned application data, thus application can run without migration.

Comment: Yes, when you clean application data, you don't need a migration but when you update an app on Google Play it is a necessary.